# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError due to the radio button

Tags: angular

i'm using angular 5 and in my html i use radio button. by checking that radio button and click a button beside can open up a modal which also contain a radio button which is checked by default. but when opening that modal causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. when i remove radio button from modal  the issue is not showing. 
[image]

here is radio button in component

```
<mat-radio-button [checked]="item.isChecked" class="mat-radio-button-sm"(click)="selectedReservation(item)"></mat-radio-button>
```

here is radio button in modal

```
<mat-radio-button [checked]="ccPayInfo?.checked" ></mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: use ngModel instead checked

Answer (score 1):

use  constructor `protected cdr:ChangeDetectorRef` dependency and `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after initialization that solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your radio-button scoped to a namespace essentially

With radio buttons, selection is assumed to be unique among grouped radio buttons (when you select one radio button, uncheck all other radio buttons)

So in this case, you don't have your radio buttons grouped together in a mat-radio-group or in a namespace and so are assumed to be part of a "global" group. This means your radio buttons interact with all the other radio buttons on your page (by clicking on the radio button outside of the modal, the modal radio button is unchecked because again selection is assumed to be unique among grouped radio buttons)

To group your radio buttons you can simply add a name:

```
<mat-radio-button name="group1" ... >
<mat-radio-button name="group1" ... >
<mat-radio-button name="group2" ... >
```

Now the radio buttons will only consider uniqueness within the scoped name.

You can also group with mat-radio-button-group

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="modelboundthinger">
    <mat-radio-button [checked]="true" ... >
    <mat-radio-button [checked]="false" ... >
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could help anybody.

I was receiving same error with

```html
      <mat-radio-group name="category">
        <mat-radio-button
          name="category"
          *ngFor="let category of categories"
          class="pulse-filter-menu-option"
          value="filterTypes[7].tempSelected.has(category.id)"
          [checked]="filterTypes[7].tempSelected.has(category.id)"
          (click)="toggleSelection(category, filterTypes[7].tempSelected)">
          {{ category.name }}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
```

I just put **value** in braces and it went away.

```html
          [value]="filterTypes[7].tempSelected.has(category.id)"
```

P.S - I wasted 3hours on this

Answer (score 0):

For me even if it was inside a mat-radio-group I needed to add the **name** attribute on my mat-radio-button to make the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

The same failure occurred, but with the following fixes.
Add a radio group and move the check attribute to the value attribute.

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="checked">
  <mat-radio-button
    *ngFor="let category of categories"
    [value]="category.id"
    (click)="() => checked = category.id">
  ></mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```